# ExtJS: Global function executes before page load. How to delay?

Tags: javascript, function, extjs, global, listeners

I've a `combobox` inside `panel` `items` and placed a `select` event in `combobox` `listeners`. Event's function calls a global method but this global function executes during page load.

I'm using this combobox selection method on several classes. Therefore a global function will be to easy. So need to use with normal behaviour during combobox's items selection. How can I achieve to this adjustment?

**Global** function:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.BaseMethods', {
    requires: [],
    singleton: true,

    // Instead of using method content several times; passing comboname and required JSON value on arguments
    comboQuery: function(comboname, JSONValue) {
        var query = Ext.ComponentQuery.query(comboname)[0].getSelectedRecord();
        var requiredValue = query.get(JSONValue);

        return requiredValue;
    },
});
```

and **Panel:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.FooPanel', {
     extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
     items: [{
         xtype: 'foocombo',
         listeners: {
             // Trying to pass required information through parameters
             select: MyApp.BaseMethods.comboQuery('[name=myfoocombo]', 'foojsonvalue'),
             scope: me
         }
     }]
 });
```

When runing this approach; Global function runs during page-load on `button` click which displays FooPanel and it's items and give error because of did not able to select combo item.;

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelectedRecord' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to delay?

No need to delay just need to change the way.

As your providing a function to [`select`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#event-select) and it will call on page load or component create so instead of this you need to call inside of `select` event function.

> I'm using this combobox selection method on several classes. Therefore a global function will be to easy. So need to use with normal behaviour during combobox's items selection. How can I achieve to this adjustment?

So for this as you mentioned  *I'm using this combobox selection method on several classes* for this you can create a common component and you can get value easily on that common component [`select`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#event-select) event.

Example

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    listeners: {
        function: select(combo, record, eOpts) {
            //you can get easily value here
            //{record} With multiSelect false, the value will be a single record. With multiSelect true, the value will be an array of records.
            record.get('you json name');
        }
    }
}
```

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2geq)**, I have created a demo. Hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        //Common Component
        //I'm using this combobox selection method on several classes.
        Ext.define('foocombo', {
            extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
            xtype: 'foocombo',
            store: {
                fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
                data: [{
                    "abbr": "AL",
                    "name": "Alabama"
                }, {
                    "abbr": "AK",
                    "name": "Alaska"
                }, {
                    "abbr": "AZ",
                    "name": "Arizona"
                }]
            },
            fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'abbr',
            JSONValue: 'name',
            listeners: {
                // Trying to pass required information through parameters
                select: function (combo, record) {
                    //As per simple way
                    console.log(record.get('name'));
                    //As per you implement
                    console.log(MyApp.BaseMethods.comboQuery(`[name=${combo.getName()}]`, combo.JSONValue))
                }
            }
        })

        Ext.define('MyApp.BaseMethods', {
            singleton: true,

            // Instead of using method content several times; passing comboname and required JSON value on arguments
            comboQuery: function (comboname, JSONValue) {
                var query = Ext.ComponentQuery.query(comboname)[0];
                if (query) {
                    var rec = query.getSelectedRecord();
                    return rec.get(JSONValue) || null;
                }
                return null
            }
        });

        Ext.define('MyApp.view.FooPanel', {
            extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
            xtype: 'foopanel',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'foocombo',
                name: 'myfoocombo'
            }]
        });

        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'foopanel',
            title: 'Demo',
            bodyPadding: 10,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Dear @N. Jadhav that is a very clear explanation. Thanks a lot.